# Magento 2: Sending Email Programmatically

Tags: php, email, magento2, amazonses

Does Magento 2 have any built-in integration with third party transaction email deliverability systems like Amazon SES, Mandrill, etc., or is the built-in email functionality still based around PHP's `mail` function?  Or are the emails sent with some third thing?

If the answer is `mail`, are there any third party extensions like SMTPPro for Magento 2 that would let a developer replace the standard email system?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I started searching around in the Magento 2 codebase for strings such as 'email', 'message', etc until I found something that sends out an email. I stumbled upon sendPaymentFailedEmail() in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Helper/Data.php`. This sets a lot of variables but eventually ties them to a transport object, which is created through a 'transportBuilder'. This transportBuilder is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder`.

In that file, a `$transport` variable exists, which is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface`. Because there is an interface, there is also a regular class called `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport`. When we open the file `vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Transport.php`, we see that this extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail;

> class Transport extends \Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail implements \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface

This is what you are looking for. Using DI, you'll be able to replace this transport with another email framework instead of Zend_Mail, such as Mandrill or Amazon SES.

Just be sure to include the `send()` method since that is the method called in `sendMessage()`;

```
public function sendMessage()
{
    try {
        parent::send($this->_message);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Magento 2 `TransportBuilder` uses a email templates to compose email's body. The simplest way I found to send plain text - use `Zend_Mail` (that is used by Magento 2 itself):

```
$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Feedback email");
$email->setBodyText($body);
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();
```

Comment: If you want to send the body in the form of html, you can use `$email->setBodyHtml($body)`

Comment: this is great, however, in case you are using smtp via something like google then follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455674/problem-when-sending-mail-with-zend-mail

Comment: I have tried this on Magento but getting an error Fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Mail' not found in /srv/public_html/pub/test.php

Comment: @NagarajuK , did you include the composer's autloader into your `/srv/public_html/pub/test.php`?

Comment: No @AlexGusev can u guide me on how to add  composer's autloader  in my test.php file?

Comment: @NagarajuK, please see code in Magento's `./index.php` or `./pub/index.php` (you need to include `./app/bootstrap.php` in your code).

Comment: I have no idea why I get unable to send mail https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326894/how-do-i-send-a-email-from-the-cron-job-magento-2

Answer (score 8):

there is an often made assumption about PHPs `mail()` beeing outdated and not supporting any 3th. party services.
That is actually wrong, as every good 3th. party service supports an SMTP interface, and so does `mail()`, too.

Amazon SES does support SMTP.

and sending via SMTP with `mail()` is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457410/716029

Comment: +1 for useful information -- but I'm still interested in what, if any, abstractions Magento has for supporting the various email via HTTP services.

Comment: No specific implementations besides Zend_Mail, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

Magento 2 Uses **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class for send custom email.

You need to create a simple module and set **email_tempaltes.xml** file for defining your transaction mail templates.

You can send mail from Adminhtml or Frontend Scope area.

I have shared a link for step by step guide to send a custom mail from Magento 2 using a module.

[Send Custom Mail from Magento 2 Module](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-mail-from-custom-module-magento-2/)