# Not able to send mails in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

I am using SMTP on my website and all the mails are working fine. I am receiving all the emails.
Now I am developing a custom script on magento root to send mails but it is not working.
This is the link that I am using to create the script.
[Magento 2: Sending Email Programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87237/magento-2-sending-email-programmatically)

This is the solution from the above link that I am using.
[image]

The code that I have created on magento root

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$objectManagerFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createObjectManagerFactory(BP, []);

$objectManager = $objectManagerFactory->create([]);

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');

$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Feedback email");
$email->setBodyText('test mail');
$email->setFrom('b2c@afsupply.com', 'AFSupply');
$email->addTo('medfosys.developer57@gmail.com', 'Rajeev');
$email->send();
```

I do not see any error message but I never receive the mails. Plz let me know what I am doing wrong as according to me this should work as the answer in the link has many upvotes. Plz suggest as I am stuck in this.

Comment: You need to use `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` for sending emails. please check https://meetanshi.com/blog/send-custom-emails-programmatically-in-magento-2/ https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-send-email-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the script in the question did not worked but then I tried to send mails using Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder as mentioned in the comment and it worked. Here is the code.

```
<?php
$templateVars = array(
                'sku' => '102365874',
                'email' => 'someEmail.com',
                'zip'   => '654321'
            );

$from = array
(
    'name' => 'Rajeev',
    'email' => 'exampleEmail.com' 
);

$transportBuilder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');

$transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('configurable_product_stock_check')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => '1'])
        ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->addTo('medfosys.developer57@gmail.com', 'Rajeev')
        ->getTransport();
        
$transport->sendMessage();
?>
```